# Cannot get gfwl source package to work in vscode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, opengl

I wanted to learn OpenGl because I was just getting into c++ and I thought it would be cool to learn but now I'm stuck and I don't know what to do.

So basically I am not using the microsoft version of VScode, I am using your basic VScode application.
I install MinGw and added it to the path.
and i created a folder, in that file i created a main.cpp file and downloaded the source folder (source package) of gfwl from the main page
and I tried different ways of including it into my cpp file
i tried
the path of gfwl from the system
<GFWL/gfwl3.h>
the files directory to gfwl3.h

and none of them seem to work, I either get a "directory or file path invalid" or errors on it failing to import its functions like gfwlinit

how could i make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to add it to the path and use a MakeFile to compile and to connect everything!